# SQL Server 2008 connection error

Tags: sql-server

Currently my project is running, however I connect same project database with SQL Server Management Studio which shows error

> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 32(The process cannot
>   access the file because it is being used by another process.) while
>   attempting to open or create the physical file 'gg.mdf'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably creating a database with the same file names (.mdf) or a database which already exists on the SQL server.

I'm not sure what type of project you are talking about but try to change the physical file names of the database or removing the existing database from the server.